# hand motion recognition using Hidden Markov Model

Tags: opencv, gesture-recognition, hidden-markov-models, feature-extraction

I'm doing hand motion recognition project for my final assigment, the core of my code is Hidden Markov Model  some papers said that we first need to detect the object, perform feature extraction then use HMM to recognize the motion,

I'm using openCV, I've done the hand detection using haar clasifier, I've prepared the hmm code using c++, but I missed something:

1. I dont' know how to integrating Haar Clasifier with HMM
2. How to perform feature extraction from detected hand (haar clasifier)?
3. I know we should first train the HMM for motion recognition, but i don't how to train motion data, what kind of data that I should use? how to prepare the data? where can I find them or how can I collect them?
4. If I searching on google, some people said that HMM motion recognition has a similiarity with HMM speech recognition, but I confused which part is similiar?

someone please tell me if I do wrong, give me suggestion what should I do

please teach me, master

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding:

1) haar is used to detect static objects, which means it works within a frame of image.

2) HMM is used to recognize temporal features, which means it works across frames.

So the things you wanna do is to first track the hand, get the feature of the hand and train the gesture movement in HMM.

As for the feature, the most naive one is the "pixel by pixel" feature. You just put all the pixels' intensities together. After this, a dimensionality reduction is needed, say, PCA.

After that, one way of using HMM is to discretize the features into clusters, and train the model with discretized states sequence, then predict the probability of a given sequence of  features belonging to each of the groups.

## Note

This is not a standard gesture recognition procedure. However it is quite naive for your "final project".

Comment: if we works with frame by frame, it means that i should use image sequences as data training, right?

Comment: Exactly. That's the way how haar and HMM is connected.